# Using if(!empty) with multiple variables not in an array

Tags: php, is-empty

I am trying to polish some code with the `if(!empty)` function in PHP but I don't know how to apply this to multiple variables when they are not an array (as I had to do previously) so if I have:

```
$vFoo       = $item[1]; 
$vSomeValue = $item[2]; 
$vAnother   = $item[3];
```

Then I want to print the result only if there is a value. This works for one variable so you have:

```
 if (!empty($vFoo)) {
     $result .= "<li>$vFoo</li>";
 }
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
if(!empty($vFoo,$vSomeValue,$vAnother) {
    $result .= "<li>$vFoo</li>"
    $result .= "<li>$vSomeValue</li>"
    $result .= "<li>$vAnother</li>"
}
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

Comment: `$result = implode('', array_map(fn($el) => "<li>$el</li>", array_filter($item)));`

Answer (score 39):

You could make a new wrapper function that accepts multiple arguments and passes each through empty(). It would work similar to isset(), returning true only if all arguments are empty, and returning false when it reaches the first non-empty argument. Here's what I came up with, and it worked in my tests.

```
function mempty()
{
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
        if(empty($arg))
            continue;
        else
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Side note: The leading "m" in "mempty" stands for "multiple". You can call it whatever you want, but that seemed like the shortest/easiest way to name it. Besides... it's fun to say. :)

**Update 10/10/13:** I should probably add that unlike empty() or isset(), this mempty() function will cry bloody murder if you pass it an undefined variable or a non-existent array index.

Comment: This should be the best answer. A succinct helper function I can reuse in multiple places.

Comment: Does this not still trigger errors if a variable is undefined, though?

Comment: Yes, see my Update at the bottom of the answer; if you pass an undefined variable or non-existent array index, it will display an error.

Comment: See: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb35e4e8460a560eca4eb5e60960952df1e88520 and click execute and you will see an error

Comment: @fdrv you would call it like this: `$var3 = mempty($var1, $var2);`. If either $var1 or $var 2 has a non-empty value it will return false, otherwise true.

Answer (score 21):

You need to write a condition chain. Use `&&` to test multiple variables, with each its own `empty()` test:

```
if (!empty($vFoo) && !empty($vSomeValue) && !empty($vAnother)) {
```

But you probably want to split it up into three ifs, so you can apply the extra text individually:

```
if (!empty($vFoo)) {
   $result .= "<li>$vFoo</li>";
}
if (!empty($vSomeValue)) {
   $result .= "<li>$vSomeValue</li>";
}
if (!empty($vAnother)) {
```

Answer (score 9):

`empty()` can only accept one argument. `isset()`, on the other hand, can accept multiple; it will return true if and only if all of the arguments are set. However, that only checks if they're set, not if they're empty, so if you need to specifically rule out blank strings then you'll have to do what kelloti suggests.

Answer (score 7):

use boolean/logical operators:

```
if (!empty($vFoo) && !empty($vSomeValue) && !empty($vAnother)) {
    $result .= "<li>$vFoo</li>"
    ...
}
```

Also, you might want to join these with `or` instead of `and`. As you can see, this can give you quite a bit of flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

I use this function as an alternative to isset. It's a little simpler than @imkingdavid's one and return true, if all arguments (variables) are not empty, or return false after first empty value.

```
function isNotEmpty() {
    foreach (func_get_args() as $val) {
        if (empty($val)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to the post by [imkingdavid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7798842/8328731);

To return `TRUE` if any of the parameters are empty, check out the below instead.

```
function mempty(...$arguments)
{
    foreach($arguments as $argument) {
        if(empty($argument)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is closer to how `isset()` works, and is how i would expect `empty()` to work if supporting a variable length of parameters. This will also keep in line with how `empty()` works in that it will return `FALSE` if everything is ***not*** empty.

---

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

*[PHP: isset - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)*

Comment: Darn. I didn't see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37573583/8328731) by [hovado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167021/hovado). My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself some typing and put it into a loop...

```
foreach (array('vFoo','vSomeValue','vAnother') as $varname) {
  if (!empty($$varname)) $result .= '<li>'.$$varname.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Isn't that simply wrong code? Wouldn't you do `foreach (array(...) AS $var)` and skip at least one of the variable variables? And anyway, I don't think this 'in' syntax exists in PHP.

Comment: +1 Absolutely right.  (What was I thinking?  Javascript?  Ugh.)  Fixed it!  I'm confident about the variable variables, though.

Comment: there is till a problem in this coe.....you need to remove the extra $ in the $varname

Answer (score 2):

As others noted, `empty()` takes only one argument so you have to use something like

```
if(!empty($v1) && !(empty($v2) ...)
```

**but** `if (!empty($v))` is the same thing as `if($v)` so you may also use:

```
if ($v1 && $v2 ...)
```

Comment: `if (!empty($v))` is **not** the same thing as `if ($v)`.  `$v` generates an error if $v is undefined, whereas `empty($v)` returns true if $v is undefined **or** evaluates to (boolean) false.

Comment: @awn: it is according to the manual, except that one does not generate a *warning*.

Comment: You're right... warning, not error.  Still, warnings mess up my page layout.

Comment: @awm: It's not even a warning. It's a notice; semantically a debug message. It indeed depends on the context if syntactic salt for notice suppression is necessary.

Comment: It's not even a warning, and it **still** messes up my page layout?  Darn that `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: check your code `if(!empty($v1) && !empty($v2) ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just loop through the $item array

```
foreach($item as $v) {
    if(!empty($v))) {
        $result .= "<li>$v</li>";
    }
}
```

You could also validate of the key index value as well

```
foreach($item as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'vFoo') {
        if(!empty($value))) {
            $result .= "<li>$value</li>";
        }
    }
    // would add other keys to check here
}
```

For the empty() versus isset()

```
$zero = array(0, "0");

foreach($zero as $z) {
    echo "\nempty(): $z ";
    var_dump($z);
    var_dump(empty($z)); // Will return true as in it's empty
    echo "isset(): $z ";
    var_dump(isset($z)); // will return true as it has value
}
```

Output:

```
empty(): 0 int(0)
bool(true)
isset(): 0 bool(true)

empty(): 0 string(1) "0"
bool(true)
isset(): 0 bool(true)
```

Comment: What's the point of `isset($v)` here?  We already know `$v` is set because it's the parameter of the foreach loop.

Comment: Pendantic note, the `isset` call is redundent here, since there is no case where `!empty($v)` will be true where `isset($v)` will be false.  So that simplifies to `!empty($v)`.  Now, if it wasn't in a loop, you should put the `isset()` call first since the variable may not be set.  But in the code you provided, just get rid of it all together...

Comment: I like to use the isset() as well to check for 0 values but I had it as &&  instead of ||.

Comment: @Phill: Hi Phill, I'm not sure I can pass them to one array as each variable has it's own name + value i.e. <li><strong>$Foo</strong>: $ValueofFoo</li>

Comment: @Nathan: I would have to print them only if they have a value, but if either of them is empty the others still need to be printed.

Comment: @Cigana Look at your own code!  `$vFoo = $item[1]; $vSomeValue = $item[2]; $vAnother = $item[3];`  Why do you have to use the named variables?  They come directly out of the `$item` array; that's why Phill wrote this!

Comment: @awm see my empty() versus isset() example

Comment: @Everyone - And there is also a new change... is not just going to be the same output result for all so one can be    <li>$variable</li> and the other can be <li>$variable<span>Some harcoded text here</span></li>, <li><a href="link.com">$variable</a></li>...Sigh... things can never be simple! :(

Comment: @Phill My point about empty() and isset() was that you never need both.  If empty() returns false, then isset() must be true.  Likewise, if isset() is false, then empty() must be true.  It isn't necessary to check both.  Use isset() *or* empty() depending on what information you need.

Comment: isset() doesn't check for zero values.  It checks for *any* value (including zero and null).

Comment: @awm in my example they are both true. I know it's a small gap but it does happen

Comment: @Phill Yes, it's possible they're both true, but they'll never both be false.  Once you've established that one is false, there's no need to check the other.

Comment: I don't agree, what if I need to check for zero? $arr = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4); foreach($arr as $v) { if(!empty($v)) { echo "Value: $v\n"; } } adding the condition || isset($v) solves that problem. sorry I work with a ton of zero strings and ints that are not false and need to validate this.

Comment: $v is always set here.  You don't need the conditional at all.

Comment: Neither isset() nor empty() can distinguish between '', null and 0.  You need === and is_null() for that.

Comment: crap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Learing everyday, now time to re-factor some code, ugh.... Thanks

Comment: @Kelloti, if I use OR within your statement, will it still not print the empty placeholders for the variables that DO NOT contain a value?

Comment: @Cigana If you accept an answer, then everything will magically work the way you want it.  I recommend the one marked "awm".

Comment: **Edit:** isset() doesn't distinguish between '', '0', 0, false, and the Array().  (*Null* should not be included here.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do, but here are a couple of possible answers:

This will return each variable only if it isn't empty:

```
function printIfNotEmpty($var) {
  if (!empty($var)) {
    return '<li>' . $var . '</var>';
  }
  return '';
}
$result .= printIfNotEmpty($vFoo);
$result .= printIfNotEmpty($vSomeValue);
$result .= printIfNotEmpty($vAnother);
```

Or this one will add all three of them if none of them are empty:

```
if (!empty($vFoo) && !empty($vSomeValue) && !empty($vAnother)) {
  $result .= '<li>' . $vFoo . '</li>';
  $result .= '<li>' . $vSomeValue . '</li>';
  $result .= '<li>' . $vAnother . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be written like this `if (!empty($vFoo && $vSomeValue && $vAnother) )`?

Answer (score 0):

Guys, many thanks for all your responses, I kind of created a script based on all of our possible answers which is actually helping me with learning PHP's syntax which is the cause behind most of my errors :) So here it is

```
$vNArray ['Brandon']  = $item[3]; 
$vNArray['Smith']= $item[4]; 
$vNArray ['Johnson']= $item[5];
$vNArray ['Murphy']= $item[6];
$vNArray ['Lepsky']= $item[7];

foreach ($vNArray as $key => $value){

    if(!empty($value)){
        $result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key</strong>"  .$value.   "</li>\n";
}
```

I just need to figure out how to make some of these different now. So could I access each in the following way?

```
$result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key[0]</strong>"  .$value. "</li>\n";
$result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li><a href="thislink.com">$key[3]</a>"  .$value. "</li>\n";
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just like this:

```
foreach(array_filter($input_array) as $key => $value) {
    // do something with $key and $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce.php) works as well.

```
if (!array_reduce($item, function($prev_result,$next) {
    return $prev_result || empty($next); // $prev_result will be initial null=false
})) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If working only with **strings**, you may try the following:

```
if(empty($str1.$str2.$str3)){ /* ... */ }
```

Note, that empty(0) would return true, while empty('0'.'0') and empty('0') won't.

Comment: I should had mentioned that this will not work that way the op asked because the equal function will return true if all strings are empty in this case. You can not use this method to validate if all strings are NOT empty, only if not all are empty: `!empty($str1.$str2)`is equal to `!empty($str1) or !empty($str2)` wich is not the same as `!empty($str1) and !empty($str2)`.

Comment: But it's an easy and short hand way to proove if all strings are empty.

Comment: why only with string?

Comment: Well, back then variables in php were not typed (not saying they are today, but it's possible now to somewhat enforce types). Also, how should the concept of emptyness be translated to other types i.e. numbers or boolenas?

Comment: variables can contain `null`, `0` or `false` values. they are all treated as empty

Comment: That is true, but not when concatenated. E.g. the number zero when concatenated will be tretaed as a string, more precisely the character '0'. https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try php `&&`/ `and` operator. They both are same.

```
if(!empty($vFoo) && !empty($vSomeValue) && !empty($vAnother) {
   $result .= "<li>$vFoo</li>"
   $result .= "<li>$vSomeValue</li>"
   $result .= "<li>$vAnother</li>"
}
```