# PHP IF condition - SHORT WAY

Tags: php

I need some help, when i have big form with a lot of data i need check if empty on server side with PHP and i need some short way to make that.

I usually work with IF, but if you have some short way to check is 20 variable empty share with me.

Original request (... dots mean a lot more variable):

```
if ($a1 != '' && $a2 != '' && $a3 != '' && $a4 != '' && $a5 != '' ...)
```

Can i write that in some short format ?
Like example:

```
if ($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5 != '')
```

Example is just how i thing to short if condition.

Comment: an array would be a start here.

Comment: No you cannot do this way.

Comment: I know that way not work, this is just example how i think to short it.

Comment: @PhpDev can you write some exmp.?

Comment: There is no native function for this. You could try the approaches here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993104/using-ifempty-with-multiple-variables-not-in-an-array or write your own.

Comment: you can try use if(empty($variable1,2,3,4))

Comment: @PhpDev its now work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create your own function that checks an array of arguments:

```
function all_elements_are_empty(...$elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $el) {
        if (!empty($el)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The `...` operator [captures all arguments passed to the function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) as the `$elements` array.

To use:

```
if (all_elements_are_empty($a, $b, $c, ...)) {
    // Do this
} else {
    // Or that
}
```