# How to use array to determine empty $_GET query string in PHP

Tags: php, forms, get

I am trying to check that all query requests from a form is filled and not hindered before proceeding with further actions.

I have a code that works already, but i would like to make it an array in other to shorten my code.

My form queries are `a,b,c`
Below is my current code:

```
if ( isset($_GET) && !isset($_GET['a']) || !isset($_GET['b']) || !isset($_GET['c']) ) 

{ //Reject call
}else{
//Process call
}
```

I wish to shorten this code with an array, here is my current code but this isn't working.

```
$supportedrequests = array('a','b','c')
if (isset($_GET) && !isset($_GET[(in_array($supportedrequests))]) ) {
{ //Reject call
}else{
//Process call
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This question is not a duplicate of [Using if(!empty) with multiple variables not in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993104/using-ifempty-with-multiple-variables-not-in-an-array) because it is specifically based on checking `isset($_GET)` query itself if it exists, and aside that, no answer was fully rendered for the said topic in the stated link.

Comment: Ah, even I need this... It would be nice. But well... Let's see...

Comment: `isset($_GET)` check is redundant, you can be sure that it will be set

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko I am also rejecting POST requests and at some point serve POST requests with different response hence why that is there.

Comment: @Praveen - The OP is contesting the hammer close. See the edit.

Comment: `if ( isset($_GET) && !isset($_GET['a']) || !isset($_GET['b']) || !isset($_GET['c']) )` - That whole statement doesn't make much sense here, as noted earlier [by Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009697/how-to-use-array-to-determine-empty-get-query-string-in-php#comment94856187_54009697). You might want to post the form for this as you say you are using one. At best, you can use a ternary operator, or a switch case.

Comment: `if (isset($_GET) && !isset($_GET[(in_array($supportedrequests))]) )` - Pretty sure you want `OR - ||` and not  `AND - &&` but I'd get rid of the first one and check if it's in the array and/or not empty.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The statement checks that 1. It is a GET request 2. All queries are present i.e a, b, c. otherwise it rejects the call. This simply means that, if the form action is changed to POST, it won't process either.

Comment: `if (isset($_GET)` - Again, don't use that and it could fail for a quite a few reasons and I can't go into detail, it would take too long.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Do you think this question needs to be opened? AFAIK, looks like a dupe again or can be solved from the comments.

Comment: @Praveen I can't make that call and rather leave it to your discretion, TBH. I feel the question can't be answered and the duplicate seems to answer it, probably to a certain extent.

Comment: @Julius ^ What do you say for the above explanation by Funk?

Comment: @Praveen Like i said, the stated duplicate isn’t related to my issue and didn’t answer my question. I will stick with my own code if no one can offer a shorter code i was asking for.

Comment: @Julius I have reopened your question coz of your determination... `:D` All the best and happy new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want check request method `GET` or `POST` use this: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`

For checking multiple parameters you can declare function and check them all.

```
function allIsset($params)
{
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (!isset($_GET[$param])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or you can use this method (if you want just less lines of code)

```
$supportedrequests = array('a','b','c');
if (count(array_intersect(array_keys($_GET), $supportedrequests)) < count($supportedrequests)) {
//reject
}
```

Comment: Second method is exactly what i needed. I just want less code for my already made solution that's all.
Thanks alot.