# check empty values PHP ​more short of code

Tags: php

Is there a way to do this, but in a shorter way? or "more professional" way? Thanks and regards. Check variables is empty (check if one is empty).

```
if((
empty($varone) || 
empty($vartwo) || 
empty($vthree) || 
empty($vardf) || 
empty($vfgsdgsdal) || 
empty($pasadfsd) || 
empty($efda) 
)) {
    $response = "There is an empty data";
    }else{$response = "NO EMPTY DATA!";}
```

Comment: Pass variables in array and run loop. if value is empty return message or you can try [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7798842/13359052)

Comment: I have added more better way to achieve your goal. Please have a look my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Firt solution, add values in array and tests if there is empty value**

```
function checkEmptyValueArray($values) {
    return !empty(array_filter($values, function ($value) {
        return empty($value);
    }));
}

$values = [$varone, $vartwo, $vthree, $vardf, $vfgsdgsdal, $pasadfsd, $efda];

if ( checkEmptyValueArray($values) ) {
    $response = "There is an empty data";
} else{
    $response = "NO EMPTY DATA!";
}
```

**An other solution is to use variable-length arguments list**

Follow this link for an explanation : https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

```
function checkEmptyValueArray(...$args) {
    foreach ( $args as $arg ) {
        if ( empty($arg) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if ( checkEmptyValueArray($varone, $vartwo, $vthree, $vardf, $vfgsdgsdal, $pasadfsd, $efda) ) {
    $response = "There is an empty data";
} else{
    $response = "NO EMPTY DATA!";
}
```

Comment: I don't know which of your solutions i prefer, both are great ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Try this more professional, simple & elegant way:

```
if (in_array("", array($varone, ..., $varN)) {
   $response = "There is an empty data";
} else {
   $response = "There is not any empty data";
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: It also works for the values you mentioned. Tested :)

Comment: Well with 0 it does not work (on php8), my bad for null ;) https://3v4l.org/3vsOV

Comment: What makes this "more professional"? I don't even know what that means in this context, tbh. Also, `empty()` checks for more things than just an empty string.